# Different Versions of jQuery Colliding When Loading a Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery in my application. I also have a header from a company which uses the older version of the jQuery. In my application I call the fancybox but sometimes the jQuery from the company gets loaded first and that does not have the definition for the fancybox. This causes the page to crash since fancybox is not found on their version of jQuery. How can I solve this problem?

If I refresh the page multiple times sometimes the page works correctly indicating that my version of jQuery was loaded first. This is a typical race condition issue.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, I have no control of what the third party company loads which they are doing to display the header and footer on the page. I also cannot go back to their version since I have lots of plugins that depend on the version I am using. (I am using the latest version of jQuery and they are using an old version of jQuery)

Comment: You should only load one version of jQuery in a page.

Comment: Dealing with multiple versions of jQuery is always a bad idea.

Comment: `if(hasFancybox) { /*use FancyBox*/ }`?

Comment: Your company has standards they follow, you cant suddenly update their website with new jQuery if they didnt really approve of it. >_>

Comment: @philtune if I use the above approve then fancybox might never gets displayed since their version of jQuery does not have fancybox. It might help with the errors but then the fancybox will never show up.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Not really a constructive comment!

Comment: @johndoe, I kinda have to agree with Fallenreaper... the issue is that jQuery needs to load consistently, and loading two different versions causes problems. I say convince the company to upgrade.

Comment: @philtune Unfortunately, convincing the company will be close to impossible!

Comment: What about `jQuery.noConflict();` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Though I guess I totally understand your situation. We use a CMS that is quite retarded and loads old versions of jQuery because it thinks it knows better than the developer. Our solution, we just have to bite the bullet and do without. Maybe there's a way to load an anonymous instance of jQuery then run your code inside that closure? Anyone?

Comment: @SamBattat's got it. From that link: `"If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version."`

Answer (score 1):

AFTER your scripts have loaded, and before theirs do, add something like this:

```
<script>
    var jQuery_1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

This changes the '$' variable to 'jQuery_1_9_1 ', and opens up the '$' for the next loaded version of jQuery (make the jQuery_1_9_1 bit whatever you like).

Here's the docs:
[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)